# Symfony: Use a value within a parameter array as a service parameter

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4, symfony-dependency-injection

Symfony 3.4

I have a parameter that looks like this:

`parameters.yml`:

```
paramters:
    some_configuration:
        param1: value1
        param2: value2
```

I want to pass a value within my `some_configuration` parameter directly to a service, rather that `some_configuration` itself. Something like this:

`services.yml`:

```
services:
    AppBundle\Service\MyService:
        arguments:
            $serviceparam: '%some_configuration.param2%'
```

Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Above Symfony 2.7.3

In all the Symfony config files I've seen, the entries under 'parameters:' have always been fully qualified.
I don't fully understand why this is but it may help you to write the entries in your `parameters.yml` like this:

`parameters.yml`:

```
parameters:
    some_configuration.param1: value1
    some_configuration.param2: value2
```

To use parameter array values in `service.yaml` you can use it as a normal parameter (like what you've written!):

`service.yaml`

```
services:
    AppBundle\Service\MyService:
        arguments:
            $serviceparam: '%some_configuration.param2%'
```

## In symfony 2.7.3:

It can be accomplished the following way:

```
services:
    AppBundle\Service\MyService:
        arguments:
            $serviceparam: ["@=container.getParameter('some_configuration')['param1']"]
```

`It works for symfony 2.7.3` 
More info about the expression language can be found in the [symfony doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#using-the-expression-language)

Answer (score 0):

```
services:
    AppBundle\Service\MyService:
        arguments:
            $serviceparam: '@=parameter("some_configuration")["param2"]'
```